# How to count number of columns in mysql that match a criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Hi i have a mysql table which has columns like DA6220_12-Apr-2016, IA6010_13-Apr-2016 and so on. Table structure :-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| DA6010_12-Apr-2016  | DA6010_13-Apr-2016 | IA6010_12-Apr-2016 | DA6220_12-Apr-2016 | 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So what i want is to count the number of columns for a particularcode like DA6010 for ex. if there is a column DA6010_12-Apr-2016 and DA6010_13-Apr-2016 then the total count of columns will be two. I know count fuction can be used to count the columns but I don't know how to count when we have a criteria or pattern involved. Is there a way to create a trigger to count automatically when any column matching DA6010 is created in the table or is there any other way to create an sql query for it.

I would be highly gratefull if anybody can help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Can this be achieved by trigger so that counting is done automatically

Comment: @Atif Can you please provide a way with triggers because there are many different codes so it would be good to do with trigger than to run individual query for all codes

Comment: something is weird here, it seems like the OP and @KartikeyVishwakarma is the same user....a sock-puppet maybe???

Comment: Atif - I agree with Kartikey because if the number of code increases so will the queries

Comment: The Flash - To clarify i don't have any relation with Kartikey but it seems like he gets my point

Comment: I am an individual entity @The Flash. I understand what he wants to achieve. I have never been good with triggers so that is why I asked if there is a way to do with a trigger

Comment: fundamentally, this problem stems from poor schema design. See normalisation; normalise your data; and your problem will magically disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Following query will give you number of columns matching your criteria

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database'   
AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'   
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'DA6010%';
```

Comment: Atif - Your solution works fine but i would be highly grateful if you can provide a way with triggers.

Comment: As of my research, triggers won't help in this case

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done by sql query. The following sql query will count the number of columns like DA6010 and return a column named total.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'   
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'   
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'DA6010%';
```